# My Cloudfront/S3 cache averages 60% misses even using Managed-CachingOptimized settings – why?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Cloudfront distribution which has a single S3 origin serving static files. These files all have `cache-control: public,max-age=31536000` (one year) as metadata, but when I view the distribution statistics, I see a consistent 60% Miss rate.

I can see that the objects with the lowest Hit rates (usually around 50%) are all from a specific folder, which my Django app uploads thumbnails to. These files still have the same headers, though, so I can't figure out why they're different.

For example – when I load this file ([S3 origin](https://scenepointblank.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/covers/a3999498817_16/819df5b152142db6bc411bf7c1e5b946.jpg), [Cloudfront link](https://static.scenepointblank.com/thumbs/covers/a3999498817_16/819df5b152142db6bc411bf7c1e5b946.jpg)) in my browser, I see a `age: 1169380; x-cache: Hit from cloudfront` headers. But if I `curl` the same URL, I see `x-cache: Miss from cloudfront` and no `age` header – if I `curl` again, the `Age` begins incrementing from 0 (and I see a `Hit`).

This feels wrong to me – the cache policy I'm using is a Cloudfront default (Managed-CachingOptimized) which doesn't forward any headers or querystrings, so why does my `curl` command trigger a call to origin when I just loaded the same file via my browser, and got a cached response?

It's possible I've misunderstood how Cloudfront is supposed to cache these files so would appreciate any pointers.

(If it helps, [this page](https://www.scenepointblank.com/reviews/browse/letter-a/) will give a bunch of URLs which show the issue, eg. any image under `https://static.scenepointblank.com/thumbs/*`)

Comment: Ah you're right – copying the `curl` command from the browser devtools results in a hit. All the static assets are served like this though (eg. via a browser's `<img>` tags) so they should all have the same accept-encoding header. I just can't figure out why these files all have such a low hit rate. It isn't because they're not accessed enough – the item with the lowest hit rate (42%) has had 52 requests, with 22 missed.

Comment: :) // Try CachingOptimizedForUncompressedObjects

Comment: Thanks, have enabled this and will monitor the results over the next few days.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary that seems to have done the trick (see the chart here: https://i.imgur.com/KNY7KDV.png) – can you post this as an answer (`CachingOptimizedForUncompressedObjects`) and I'll accept :)